# how to filter array in reactJS with 2 condistions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to filter the array with two conditions but without success, it only refers to the second condition, each condition individually works great.

The original task :
"When entering a text in the    “search”    text    box,    the users   list    will    presents    anly    users   that
their   name    or  email   contains    that    text

```
const filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter((filuser) => {
  return (
    filuser.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase()) ||
    filuser.email.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
  );
});
```

Comment: Can you add the data and expected results?

Comment: The expected result is that if I enter in the search box the values: "ab"
So as a result I will also get a username that contains these values ​​and also an email address if one exists with these values.

Comment: I used your code and it seems work fine. some other parts of your code have problems probably. check the online sample here. (https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-leaf-hddkb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter((filuser) => {
  const {searchfield} = this.state
  return (
    `${filuser.name} ${filuser.email}`.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchfield)>-1
});
```

Comment: Work great! You just forget add ) befor })

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my way to multiple filter data.https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-wildflower-fuio1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Move the constant data to outside of component and state have only filtered data. Each time when you apply the filters, always use the `initial data (all_data)`.

Here is update code. (try name `abc` and email `def`, it will show 2 results)
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-leavitt-t2wsr

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const all_data = [
  {
    names: "abc",
    emails: "abc@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    names: "def",
    emails: "def@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    names: "ghi",
    emails: "ghi@gmail.com"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState(all_data);
  const nameFilter = ({ names }) =>
    names.toUpperCase().includes(name.toUpperCase());
  const emailFilter = ({ emails }) =>
    emails.toUpperCase().includes(email.toUpperCase());
  const handleSearch = () => {
    // const filterData = data.filter(nameFilter).filter(emailFilter);
    const filterData = all_data.filter(
      (obj) => nameFilter(obj) || emailFilter(obj)
    );
    setData(filterData);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="email"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>Search</button>
      {data.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <p>{item.names}</p>
            <p>{item.emails}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```